# Python: How to save rgb float image?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I try to save RGB float image to tiff file, but i cannot find a way to do it.

```
from PIL import Image
imgf = np.ones((5,5,3),dtype = np.float32)
img_to_save = Image.fromarray(imgf) #fails..
img_to_save.save('img.tiff')
```

Alternatively, matplotlib.pyplot imsave change my floats to ints.

How can i do it?

Comment: There are variuos libs available to do that. For Example the libtiff or if I remember correctly also the PIL (Python Image Library)

Comment: Assuming `plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot`, you have the arguments to `plt.imsave` reversed.  It should be `plt.imsave(test_file_name, imgf)`.  If that works for you, you don't need to create an `Image`.  `imsave` can create the file from the numpy array.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser plt.imsave change floats to ints

Comment: Looks like Pillow doesn't support floating point RGB: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes

Comment: You could try `tifffile`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile

Comment: @Warren Weckesser. Thanks!! You are right.    tifffile did it.
However now i cannot find a viewer that can show me the values (imageJ cannot) of the image.